# Should I use Comand Prompt or Vs Code terminal for installing modules, running projects ...etc?

Tags: python, django

I've seen many videos using Comand Prompt to start with a project. Why they use it when you can do it in thier respective IDE's terminal ?

Both work the same i guess? I'm confused.

Does anyone know which is better to use?

Comment: There's not much a difference; It's mainly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: better you use command prompt as administrator while installing modules

Comment: Perhaps because command prompt is IDE-agnostic; it'll work for any system. In contrast, using an IDE's terminal would only make sense to a watcher if the watcher is also using that same IDE, which they may not.